# Can set title color of UIButton only once, not twice

Tags: iphone, ios5

I initiated my button like this:

```
meetingPointButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[meetingPointButton setTitle:@"Alpha" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[meetingPointButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Afterwards I change its title and when doing so also want to alter the title color. I am using following code:

```
[meetingPointButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[meetingPointButton setTitle:@"Beta" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The title changes to "Beta" but its color stays light gray. Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As prince said use:

```
meetingPointButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Leaving out `forState:UIControlStateNormal` makes the button switch right away instead of the next time it recieves to go to UIControlStateNormal. Knowing this you could also just set the button to `UIControlStateNormal` after your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 meetingPointButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

to change text color.

Answer (score 0):

For people that might be coming to this question on the basis of the title, one reason you might not see an effect when you change the color of the title is because the `UIButton`'s string might be an `NSAttributedString`. `UIButton` has special methods to set an attributed string for the title and when a title is set that way setting the title text color has no effect. You need to change the attributed title `NSAttributedString` instead.